# Show teams which user is member of

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I show which teams a user is a member of?

My homepage for logged in users:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="display-3">Your Teams</h1>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

My user.rb model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :teams, through: :memberships
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

end
```

My team.rb model:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, through: :memberships
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end
```

My membership.rb model:

```
class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access to them using `.groups` within an instance of `User`. Considering an instance `@my_user` initialized in a controller, writing this code in your HTML should print many `<h2>` tags, one for each group:

(Assume you have the string property `name` in your `Group` class)

```
<% @my_user.groups.each do |group| %>
  <h2><%= group.name %></h2>
<% end %>
```

The `has_many` keyword on your class `User` does all the magic, you are already telling the class to get the groups `through :memberships`.